# Windows 10 Vagrant is stopping at "SSH auth method: private key"

Tags: windows, ssh, vagrant

When I run `vagrant up` from the command line, it is a crap shoot at best as to whether vagrant will boot up or not.  It stops at this line:

```
SSH auth method: private key
```

And then may or may not include this line:

```
Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
```

As I said, sometimes it works and sometimes it does not.  Why is this problem happening?  For the record it would happen (less often) on my production MacBook at work.

Can I maybe change the auth method if there is no good answer for this?  Trust me I have been looking and not found any answer on this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whats happening is the following :

- vagrant up will spin a new VM, basically it contacts virtualbox (or the specific provider) and run command to start a VM
- the VM will start on the virtualbox side

note: if you run form a command line terminal in macos, you can see the title switching from 'Ruby' to 'VBoxManage'

- the VM takes some time to start
- because the VM does not send a specific signal when its done, vagrant will check at regular interval if the VM is fully booted and available to ssh-in
- once the VM is available, vagrant can run the ssh command and complete the config (network, shared folder, etc...)

so in your case, the VM takes a bit longer to boot (this can be due to high activity on your mac, specific setup of the VM that runs on boot ...)

Basically this is harmless and is not necessarily a bad sign.

Comment: ++ for this clear explanation of how it works conceptually (in spite of the downvote on my post :) ).  I now understand that the network settings and shared folder [two essential features needed to use the VM] are handled by Vagrant but the boot-up by the provider - yes, in my case VirtualBox.  Thanks

Comment: One comment and question though: I am currently using Windows 10 not MacOS (regrettably) and if the Vagrant boot-up does hang regularly, what would you look at next?

Comment: I am not experienced much on windows, might be it takes a bit more time to initiate the ssh connection

Answer (score 0):

Please look at my accepted answer on this.  It turns out that this was a memory allocation issue, and I only discovered it when watching the terminal for the VM provider (VirtualBox).  Once I closed some programs I was (generally) able to boot up just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an incompatibility problem with Vagrant/VirtualBox & the Windows Hypervisor Platform feature in Windows 10

I had this problem and this is how I got get Vagrant & WSL2 working side by side

I have the following environment:

- Hardware Virtualization enabled in BIOS
- Windows 10 (Insider Program with Release Preview Channel)

  -- Windows 10 with WSL 2 Version 10.0.19041 Build 19041
- VirtualBox 6.1.12

  -- Extension Pack Installed
- Vagrant 2.2.9

These are the settings that worked for me:

- Windows Hypervisor Platform: Off
- Virtual Machine Platform: On
- Windows Subsystem for Linux: On

[image]